# Set Voice on Turn by Turn Navigation in HERE sdk ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, here-api

I am using **HERE** map. I am trying to set voice on turn by turn navigation but i am not able to do that. i tried with `NMAVoicePackage` to set voice but i don't know how to set. following code is what i try.

```
NMAVoiceCatalog *voiceCatalog = [NMAVoiceCatalog sharedVoiceCatalog];
NMAVoicePackage *voicepackeg=[voiceCatalog.voicePackages objectAtIndex:0];
[voiceCatalog installVoicePackage:voicepackeg]
 [[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager] setVoicePackage:voicepackeg];

   NSError *error;
    NSLog(@"starting navigation simulation");
    error = [[NMANavigationManager sharedNavigationManager] startTurnByTurnNavigationWithRoute:self.route];

    if(error && error.code != NMANavigationErrorNone){
        NSLog(@"ERROR: failed to start simulation with error code %ld", (long)error.code);
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu could you please provide me the sample for turn turn by navigation?

Comment: @SourabhSharma turn by turn navigation [here](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/map-guidance.html).

Comment: Yes I am trying to implement it as given in documentation. But With no success. Could you mail the sample you made on turn by turn after reading the doc. I am struck here. I am not good in objective c. Please help.

Comment: @SourabhSharma i didn't made sample.

Comment: https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/ExtendedSwiftExample.zip

Use this sample man

Comment: @SourabhSharma i don't know swift. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check your Navigation Mode set as driving.

Voice instructions are only available in Navigation Mode for driving. Users of the pedestrian Navigation Mode receive audio beeps and vibrations alerts at the change of each maneuver. [Link](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/ios-hybrid-plus/topics/map-voice-instructions.html)